# Using datediff to find the lowest value with a given gap between rows

Tags: sql, t-sql

So i have a table that ive called tasks and looks like this:

```
Tasks
Date_from datetime
Date_to datetime
user string
```

An example of some rows look like this (its yyyy:mm:dd):

```
Date_from   Date_to    user
2014-06-01  2014-11-10 Garry
2014-11-11  2015-01-01 Garry
2015-01-02  2015-05-15 Garry

2015-06-01  2015-08-29 Garry
2015-30-01  2015-12-30 Garry
```

Most of the tasks stop one day and the next one starts the very next day. 
What im trying to figure out how to do is to get the lowest date_from that Garry has for starting a task, but if there is a gap in his tasks (like ive shown with the blank line) i want to get the first one where the number of days between the last date_to and date_from are greater than for example 10 days.

Ive been trying to use datediff to do this, but ive not been able to get it rigth if its possible:

```
select max(a.date_from) as lowest_date
from Tasks a 
where datediff(dd, 
    (select max(date_to) 
    from Tasks b 
    where b.date_from > a.date_to 
    and b.user= a.user),  a.date_from
    ) >= 10
and a.user = 'Garry'
```

At first i tried to use min(a.date_from), but that would not work if there was 2 places where there existed a gap it would take the first one instead of the latest one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server 2012+, you would use `lag()`.  You can get the gaps using logic like this:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(date_to) over (partition by user order by date_from) as prev_date_to
      from tasks t
     ) t
where datediff(day, prev_date_to, date_from) > 10;
```

Getting the first gap for each user is a bit trickier:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by user
                                order by (case when datediff(day, prev_date_to, date_from) > 10 then 1, else 2 end),
                                         date_from asc
                               ) as seqnum
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(date_to) over (partition by user order by date_from) as prev_date_to
            from tasks t
           ) t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks ive been trying to use what you suggested, but i seem to be running into some problems and im not quite sure how they come about. for some reason the prev_date_to does not always match the users registered dates could you point me in the rigth direction? [http://imgur.com/aqHgkGz](picture top = what i get from your suggestion, bottom is the tasks on the same user in the database)

Comment: so after some fiddeling im finding that i get the rigth result if i put "select t.*,
                   lag(date_to) over (partition by user order by date_from) as prev_date_to
            from tasks t where user = 'Garry'", now i just have to figure how how i can do this to everyone instead of using the static user id

Comment: If you can updated your question to include more than one user in the sample data, and add expected output, maybe we can help with this.

Comment: so i managed to get it working, thanks so much. Get exactually what i wanted to find